# iOS panoramic app: PanoramaView porting on swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, 360-panorama

I need to show some 360 degree spherical photos and was trying to use the [RobbyCraft's Panorama repository](https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama) on Github. I'm able to get the Obj-C project running well, but I don't understand on how use the swift example described by Fabien [here](https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama/issues/38).

(By the way I know that I can also use the Google Maps API to render panoramic photos, but I'm afraid that it's a more complicated approach for my needs...)

I made a swift app with a GLKitViewController. Obviously I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'panoramaView'...
Must I use the "Bridging-Header.h" declaration ? (I mean #import "PanoramaView.h")?

I tried to do so, but then I'll get many errors on PanoramaView.h itself.

[image]

(PS. I added the needed frameworks to my project, too)

[image]

Comment: Check how did you add bridging header, is it visible for your project or not. https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/

Answer (score 0):

In the `Bridging-Header.h` file add the following line on top

```
#import "PanoramaView.m"
```

Answer (score 0):

In PanoramaView.h, at the top add

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
```

I had same problem and this solved it